# JDBC resultset count (number of rows)

Tags: java, jdbc

JDBC API has provided a rich set of functions for the programmers to carry on the database operations. I am surprised what restricted them to provide a function such as getCount() that will return the number of rows obtained by executing a query.

Comment: Please specify the reason for the down vote.

Comment: I dont get it either :/  Your question makes sense. Have an upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the up vote Deepak. Those who have down voted seems to be over smart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get back when you execute a query is a result set that iterates over the rows. A database need not necessarily return information on how many rows a query fetches, since it may decide to optimize the fetch and only return say the first X rows.

You can always get the count of the rows in the same transaction and obtain the information you want. Another option is to use a [scrollable resultset](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/sql/scrollable-resultset-example/) and traverse to the last row and then get the row count.

[**EDIT**]

An [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138427.html#18) from the Oracle tech network recommends what I just wrote in my answer, albeit they do not provide the internal technical reason behind it.

Comment: I agree with you Deepak, but still we need to move the cursor to the last and then do the getRow to get the count in case of a scrollable result set. May be what you are saying is correct, "it may decide to optimize the fetch and only return say the first X rows", still it should return that X count.

Comment: If it did that the result of `getCount()` would be inaccurate. Say a query returns 1 million rows but the DB decides to fetch only 10 rows and get them ready for traversal of the `ResultSet`. The next 10 rows would be fetched when they are needed. In this case the answer is 1 million and not 10.